# Mapping Servlet and HTML form

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets

Problem with servlet is that, I have to maintain consistency of names across HTML form and Servlet,

```
String data = request.getParameter(FIELD_NAME);
```

and

```
<input name=FIELD_NAME ...>
```

Is there any standard practice to avoid such inconsistency? Also is it possible to make servlet reusable, so that we can add new fields in form without modifying Servlet code?

Comment: This is among others where component based [MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3541077) frameworks like [JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) come into the picture. Perhaps it's time to pick and learn one?

Comment: Thanks! Till I learn JSF, is there any quick solution?